# Data Syncrhonization between daemon and Django protocol

Tags: windows, django, odbc, synchronization

I'm currently working on a web application which shows data about remote microcontollers which collect weather data. Data is sent to an application through a proprietary protocol, and ends up being stored in a ODBC accessible database in a Windows machine.
I've written a Django application, taking a snapshot of that data, showing those remote units as Google Map Markers that show a nice Google Visualization plot. Up to this point, everything went just fine.

The problem I'm facing here is that the ODBC accesible database is running in a Windows machine and the Django app in a remote server under Linux.

I need to synchronize data from the Windows box to the remote django app. I'm planning to write a transaction-oriented sync protocol. But I don't want it to be too complex, though I must prevent stalled sync states.

Any thoughts about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a RESTful API with TastyPie on the server, and a PyQt4 GUI in the client using httplib2 as client library.
Since I'm using Python 2.7, I use native json module (which tastes much like simplejson).
Final notes, I'm building an executable with cxfreeze.